# Passing multiple actions to bindActionCreators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I can't seem to find a concrete answer to this question.

If I have a connected component, and I want to pass in multiple actions from different reducers:

```js
import { actions as commonActions } from 'some/action/file';
import { actions as userActions } from 'another/action/file';
```

Can I use `bindActionCreators` like so in my `mapDispatchToProps` call...?

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators((commonActions, userActions), dispatch)
});
```

or must I have to pass them in like

```js
actions: bindActionCreators({ ...commonActions, ...userActions }, dispatch);
```

They are passed in like the latter all across the app I work on, but I am going through cleaning and updating the app, and am looking to minimize anywhere I can. Is the former acceptable, or do they have to be passed in as destructured objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use Object.assign:

```
return {
     actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, commonActions, userActions), dispatch) 
};
```

You could call the actions directly on the store so that you could remove the bindActionCreators:
`this.props.store.dispatch(sendMessage())`

[This article](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/) by Mark Erikson goes into more detail and provides alternatives to bindActionCreators as he advises not to use it.

Comment: `Object.assign` works, yes, but we use ES7, which is why I used the destructured way. And unfortunately I cannot move away from `bindActionCreators` on the app that I work on...